# What is the meaning of "ongoing requirement"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Would you please tell me the meaning of "ongoing requirement"?

I surveyed it on the internet but couldn't find out the proper meaning. Close synonym is "continuous", but I think it's a little different from the context.

The original sentence is like this:

> You should ensure that all staff are appropriately trained about the ongoing requirement for penetration testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the requirement can’t be satisfied just once. It needs to be maintained. For example, suppose you work in academia. Publishing a journal paper requires only that it be accepted. Even if you stop publishing from then on, the paper will stay in the journal. In contrast, your university contract might require you to publish 2 papers every year. Just because you published 2 papers last year doesn’t mean you can avoid publishing any next year - it’s an *ongoing* requirement.

In the case of security, just because you showed last month that nothing could get through your firewall, it doesn’t mean you’re allowed to stop testing - maybe a new virus could get through next month. So *penetration testing* is an ongoing requirement - you need to keep doing it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I understand the real meaning.

Answer (score 1):

"Ongoing Requirement" means the requirement that is continuing [not continuous]; which is still in progress.